# Increase GRUB time

Tags: grub2

I recently installed ubuntu (dual boot with windows).
Right now this is the way it is set up:
The GRUB screen shows up and after 20 seconds it boots onto Linux (If I choose windows within that 20 seconds, then I can choose to load windows.)

How do I make the GRUB screen stay on for much longer and not just 20 seconds so that I can manually choose to load linux or windows?
Sometimes I turn on the computer and leave for a while and come back to see linux loaded automatically.

Ty

Comment: I have to say don not leave for a while you will not be able to set that timer to minutes.

Answer (score 0):

In /etc/default/grub find and change the value of GRUB_TIMEOUT to -1 to wait indefinitely or you can set a bigger value.

Don't forget to run after modification:
`sudo update-grub`